# How to get userId using bridge table Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am working in a project and I want to check for user id before let him update or delete. I use Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC for that.

Table 1 is

```
public class User {
    public int UserId { get; set; }  

    // more stuff here. 

    public ICollection<UserPost> UserPost{get; set;}
}
```

Here is my second table

```
public class Post {
    public int PostId { get; set; } 

    // more stuff 

    public ICollection<UserPost> UserPost{get; set;}
}
```

This is my last one:

```
public class UserPost {
    public int userPostId { get; set; }
    public int userId {get; set; }
    public int postId {get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public virtual User Post{ get; set; }
    // and more 
}
```

In my view I want to check for user to update or delete his posts like this code but it does not work.

```
@model List<MyFinalProject.Core.Domain.Post>
// Razor syntax here 
    @if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin") ||
                            Model[i].UserPost.Where(u => u.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()))
                        { // some logic }
```

Comment: Try troubleshooting your view by just checking the first part of the conditional if...then test the second part (after the 'or' || ). I'd guess it's the second part of the logic that's the problem. If so, avoid using linq logic. Rather: Model[i].UserPost.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserID() or something like that...hope this helps.

Comment: Yap My problem is in the second part of the condition after ( || ) I tried using  Model[i].UserPost.UserId but I could not get an access for it. @SRQCoder

Answer (score 1):

Have you added an identity service for the **Users** to the *ConfigureServices()* at the *Startup.cs*?

For more info abot **AspNet.Identity** check this:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authentication/introduction-to-aspnet-identity.html

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for your help I just found the answer and I want to share it with you. I only change the second part after (||) condition to:

```
@if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated && User.IsInRole("Admin") ||
                     Model[i].UserPost.Any(e => e.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId<int>()))
```